# Mongoose populate multiples ids

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, population

I have these schemas

```
var DriverSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  groups: {
     type: String,
     ref: 'DriverGroup'
  }
});


var DriverGroupSchema = Schema({
  name: String
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('DriverGroup', DriverGroupSchema);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Driver', DriverSchema);
```

I have these driver groups:

```
[{
  id: '12345',
  name: 'Group1'
}, {
  id: '6789',
  name: 'Group2'
}]
```

and this driver:

```
{
  name: 'Driver1',
  groups: '12345,6789'
}
```

How I can get the groups by population? I am using this:

```
Driver.find().sort('name').populate('groups')
```

But does not works properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're storing `groups` incorrectly, if you want to populate them in this way.
`populate` cannot parse a string in order to determine the separate entities.

It should be an array

```
groups: '12345,6789'
```

should be

```
groups: ['12345,6789']
```

Also, populate works by looking up the _ids (not name field)

So, will need to change your schema:

```
var DriverSchema = Schema({
  name: String,
  groups: [{ type: string, ref: 'DriverGroup' }]
});
```

You'll need to set the `_id` too (set `_id` to same as `name` in your case)

```
var DriverGroupSchema = Schema({
  _id: String,
  name: String
});
```

http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html